# simple opendir() with pagination

Tags: php, pagination, opendir

I am very new in php, though was wable to make opendir() work (just show list of files in a table) now I have a problem of creating a pagination. Sorry I have been working with tutorials out there but can't make them work.I quick help would be very much appreciated.

here's my code:

```
$dir = 'files/memoranda'; 
$exclude = array('.','..','.htaccess'); 
$y = (isset($_GET['y']))? strtolower($_GET['y']) : ''; 
$res = opendir($dir); 

while(false!== ($file = readdir($res))) { 
if(strpos(strtolower($file),$y)!== false &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) { 
echo'
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
            <h4><a  href=" ' . $dir .  '/' . $file . ' ">'.$file.'</a></h4>
        </div>

        <div id="Cell" style="text-align: center;vertical-align:middle;border-top:solid 1px #cecece;">
            <h4><a href=" ' . $dir .  '/' . $file . ' "><img style="text-align:center;padding-top:6px;" src="icon_download.png" width="30px" height="30px" ></a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
';

} 
}
```

Comment: One option is to use the `array_slice()` function, eg http://stackoverflow.com/a/31227344/61795

Comment: there was something like this. here is link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543324/how-to-add-pagination-in-scandir-php/30543855#30543855

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your responses, got me going.. but this is like my first day doing php.. sorry if your responses could've been very obvious, but can't make any sense of most of them. looking at my code, got a quick question, I tried locating where I can find the array, all I found on array_count echo is like 1,1,1,1 not a real value.. can anyone help?